# Delete or replace first value of a list SUBLIME

Tags: regex

```
(1, 1111, 999999),
(2, 2222, 45000),
(3, 333, 999999),
(4, 44444, 100000),
(5, 555555, 100000)
    ...
```

I have this list which are sql lines, that goes on forever,
How do I delete the first value of each line in () such as 1,2,3,4,5 using sublime?

Result I need:

```
(1111, 999999),
(2222, 45000),
(333, 999999),
(44444, 100000),
(555555, 100000)
```

I have tried to use `(?<=firstString)\d+(?=secondString)` this, using "(" and "," respectively but "(" is being read as part of the expression.

Comment: Try `\(\d+,\h*` and replace with `(`. Could you please add the exact pattern you tried to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

*Find*:      `\(\d+,\h*`
*Replace*: `(`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QsDojn/1).

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(` char (note: to match a literal `(` char, you need to prepend it with `\`)
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `,` - a comma
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces (I prefer `\h` to `\s` since `\s` also matches linebreaks, and you need to stay on the same line).

The `(` is the replacement pattern as you need to restore the `(` that was matched and replaced.

**NOTE**: To only match at the start of a line, prepend the pattern with `^`:

```
^\(\d+,\h*
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the start of each line, and replace up to the first space with a `(`:

Find: `\(\d+,\s`

Replace: `(`